# Color de la fuente en las columnas de un UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c

No se como cambiar el color de los elementos dentro de un `UIPickerView`.

Como veis en la captura lo único que necesito es que todos los textos sean azules, acorde al resto de la aplicación.

Ahora los textos y los números me salen en negro que el color por defecto del picker.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy simple, solo tienes que implementar uno de sus métodos delegados para devolver un `NSAttributedString`.
Por ejemplo, la implementación completa de tu caso sería algo tal que así:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 2

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return component == 0 ? 31 : 4

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    if component == 0 {

        return NSAttributedString(string: "\(row)", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor])

    } else {

        switch row {
        case 0:
            return NSAttributedString(string: "días", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor])
        case 1:
            return NSAttributedString(string: "semanas", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor])
        case 2:
            return NSAttributedString(string: "meses", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor])
        case 3:
            return NSAttributedString(string: "años", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor])
        default:
            return nil
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta. Funciona perfecto.